# Avoid duplicate data for database

Tags: javascript, php

I have dropdown position like general account and treeview within checkbox. So, first the user choose position and select the checkbox then submit. Its okay. Next, when refresh for dropdown general manager it will have the previous selected treeview within checkbox. But, when I untick some treeview and submit, the database still fetch the untick treeview. That's why it have duplicate data. How can I manage it? Its supposed to check duplicate data before insert and be update the new record and delete the existing data.

**JavaScript for button submit**

```
//AJAX call for button
    $("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
    var button = $("#primaryTextButton").data("kendoButton");
    button.bind("click", function(e) {

    var test = $("#dropdown").val()

    $.ajax({
        url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/testing.php",
        type: "post",
            data: {'id':test,'progid':array},
                success: function () {
                // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 
                    kendo.alert('Success'); // alert notification
                },
        });
```

**PHP for database**

```
$propertyID = "1";
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/EHORS.pdo.php'); 
$ehorsObj = new EHORS();
$ehorsObj->EHORS_CONNECT($propertyID);

global $ehorsObj;
$employeeID = $_SESSION['employeeID'];
$propertyID = $_SESSION['propertyID'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$progid = $_POST['progid'];

for($x=0; $x< sizeof($progid); $x++ )
{
    $array = array();   

$positionTemplateID = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK("tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate"); 
$sqlAdd = "INSERT INTO tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate 
            SET positionTemplateID = '" . $positionTemplateID . "',
            programID = '" . $progid[$x] . "',
            hrsPositionID  = '" . $id . "',
            propertyID   = '" . $propertyID . "',
            employeeID  = '" . $employeeID . "',
            dateTimeEmployee = NOW() ";     

$ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAdd, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);

$positionTemplateIDLog = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK("tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog");   
$sqlAddLog = "INSERT INTO tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog 
            SET positionTemplateIDLog = '" . $positionTemplateIDLog . "',
            positionTemplateID = '" . $positionTemplateID . "',
            programID = '" . $progid[$x] . "',
            hrsPositionID  = '" . $id . "',
            propertyID   = '" . $propertyID . "',
            employeeID  = '" . $employeeID . "',
            dateTimeEmployee = NOW() ";     

$ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAddLog, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
  }
```

Anyone have some solution on this?
[Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keLJA.png)

Comment: Please add an example of array with and without duplicate data.

Comment: Input: List = [1, 10, 2, 2, 10, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
Output: List = [1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5]. It shoud be like this example.

Comment: Please edit your post to specifically ask for how to eliminate duplicates from an array since you are asking to clean up the duplicates from the data that you will be sending to your back end. This will also serve as `javascript` specific problem only, so you can edit accordingly and remove unnecessary code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following example:

```
let input = [1, 10, 2, 2, 10, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5];
let output = []; // [1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can loop through the elements in `input` and push to another collection/array if it does not exist in it yet.

```
input.forEach(element => {
    if (!output.includes(element))
        output.push(element);
});
```

There are other ways to eliminate duplicates in array:

**1. Using [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```
myArray.filter((element, index) => myArray.indexOf(element) === index );
```

**2. Using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**

```
myArray.reduce(
   (newArray, element)=> { 
      return newArray.incudes(element)? newArray: [...newArray, element];
   }, 
   []
);
```

**3. Using ES6 [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)**

```
[...new Set(myArray)]
```